# Finding the volume of the tetrahedron using triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

$D$ is the tetrahedron bounded by the coordinate planes and the plane $3x+3y+z=3$, then express the volume of $D$ as a triple integral.

**Mt Try:**

The z-limits are $0\le z\le3-3x-3y$

If $y$ is the limit on the $xy$- plane then $z=0$ $0\le y\le1-x$

Similarly, $0\le x\le3$

Finally, the integral will be $\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{3-3x-3y}dz\ dy\ dx$

Is my above integral correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct for $y$ and $z$ bounds but for $x$ we have

- $y=z=0 \implies x=1 \implies 0\le x \le 1$

and therefore

$$V=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{1-x}dy\int_{0}^{3-3x-3y}dz$$